# Finding __metaclass__ used before redefinition in Python

Tags: python, metaclass

I want to redefine a __metaclass__ but I want to fall back to the metaclass which would have been used if I hadn't redefined.

```
class ComponentMetaClass(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):

        return <insert_prev_here>.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)


class Component(OtherObjects):
     __metaclass__ = ComponentMetaClass
```

From what I understand, the __metaclass__ used by default goes through the process of checking for a definition in the scope of the class, then in the bases and then in global. Normally you would use type in the redefinition and that is usually the global one, however, my OtherObjects, may have redefined the __metaclass__. So in using type, I would ignore their definition and they wouldn't run, right?

edit: note that I don't know what OtherObjects are until runtime

Comment: That sounds right. Is it not behaving as expected when you run it?

Comment: it doesn't work with <insert_prev_here> on the metaclass :) I'm looking for the answer to what I can substitute in there to call the used metaclass if I hadn't redefined it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @unutbu puts it: "Within one class hierarchy, metaclasses must be subclasses of each other. That is, the metaclass of Component must be a subclass of the metaclass of OtherObjects."

Which means your problem is a bit more complicated than you though first - Not only you have to call the proper metaclass from the base classes, but your current metaclass has to properly inherit from then as well.

(hack some code, confront strange behavior,  come back 90 min later)
It was tricky indeed - I had to create a class that receives the desired metaclass as a parameter, and which __call__ method generates dynamically a new metaclass, modifying its bases and adding a __superclass attribute to it.

But this should do what you want and some more - you just have to inherit all your metaclasses from `BaseComponableMeta` and call the superclasses in the hyerarchy through the metaclass "__superclass" attribute:

```
from itertools import chain

class Meta1(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, dct):
        print name
        return type.__new__(metacls, name, bases, dct)

class BaseComponableMeta(type):
    def __new__(metacls, *args, **kw):
        return metacls.__superclass.__new__(metacls, *args, **kw)

class ComponentMeta(object):
    def __init__(self, metaclass):
        self.metaclass = metaclass
    def __call__(self, name, bases,dct):
        #retrieves the deepest previous metaclass in the object hierarchy
        bases_list = sorted ((cls for cls in chain(*(base.mro() for base in bases)))
        , key=lambda s: len(type.mro(s.__class__)))   
        previous_metaclass = bases_list[-1].__class__
        # Adds the "__superclass" attribute to the metaclass, so that it can call
        # its bases:
        metaclass_dict = dict(self.metaclass.__dict__).copy()
        new_metaclass_name = self.metaclass.__name__ 
        metaclass_dict["_%s__superclass" % new_metaclass_name] = previous_metaclass
        #dynamicaly generates a new metaclass for this class:
        new_metaclass = type(new_metaclass_name, (previous_metaclass, ), metaclass_dict)
        return new_metaclass(name, bases, dct)

# From here on, example usage:

class ComponableMeta(BaseComponableMeta):
    pass

class NewComponableMeta_1(BaseComponableMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, *args):
        print "Overriding the previous metaclass part 1"
        return metacls.__superclass.__new__(metacls, *args)

class NewComponableMeta_2(BaseComponableMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, *args):
        print "Overriding the previous metaclass part 2"
        return metacls.__superclass.__new__(metacls, *args)

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta1


class B(A):
    __metaclass__ = ComponentMeta(ComponableMeta)

# trying multiple inheritance, and subclassing the metaclass once:
class C(B, A):
    __metaclass__ = ComponentMeta(NewComponableMeta_1)

# Adding a third metaclass to the chain:
class D(C):
    __metaclass__ = ComponentMeta(NewComponableMeta_2)

# class with a "do nothing" metaclass, which calls its bases metaclasses:  
class E(D):
    __metaclass__ = ComponentMeta(ComponableMeta)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! even though I solved the problem I was having through the usage of super (check comments on unubtu's answer), I believe this solution is really the ultimate solution for people who come across a similar problem. 
I don't really understand the ComponentMeta part though :P

Comment: Yes, it combines a lot of black magic - but it ultimately recreates each metaclass dynamically (through the call to `type`), using as base the "deep most" metaclass of all the class bases. It could actually be a function returning another function, instead of a class implementing `__call__` - it'd work just the same.

Answer (score 1):

Within one class hierarchy, metaclasses must be subclasses of each other. That is, the metaclass of `Component` must be a subclass of the metaclass of `OtherObjects`.

If you don't name a `__metaclass__` for `Component` then the metaclass of `OtherObjects` will be used by default.

---

If `ComponentMetaClass` and `OtherObjectsMeta` both inherit (independently) from `type`:

```
class OtherObjectsMeta(type): pass
class ComponentMetaClass(type): pass

class OtherObjects(object):
    __metaclass__ = OtherObjectsMeta

class Component(OtherObjects):
     __metaclass__ = ComponentMetaClass
```

then you get this error:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

but if you make `ComponentMetaClass` as subclass of `OtherObjectsMeta`

```
class ComponentMetaClass(OtherObjectsMeta): pass
```

then the error goes away.

---

Perhaps I misread your question. If want `ComponentMetaClass.__new__` to call `OtherObjectsMeta.__new__`, then use `super`:

```
class OtherObjectsMeta(type): 
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        print('OtherObjectsMeta')
        return super(OtherObjectsMeta,meta).__new__(meta,name,bases,dct)
class ComponentMetaClass(OtherObjectsMeta):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        print('ComponentMetaClass')
        return super(ComponentMetaClass,meta).__new__(meta,name,bases,dct)
```

---

Regarding an alternative to using metaclasses, mentioned in the comments. Use `super`:

```
class Base(object):
    def method(self): pass

class Base1(Base):
    def method(self):
        print('Base1')
        super(Base1,self).method()

class Base2(Base): 
    def method(self):
        print('Base2')
        super(Base2,self).method()

class Component(Base1,Base2):
    pass

c = Component()
c.method()
```

Comment: So.. lets say I wanted to know which metaclass I needed to subclass? How would I ago about finding that, do I have to recursively search a definition of __metaclass__ in the bases until I reach one? assuming that's the process done by the default class defintion.
Note that I don't know what OtherObjects are until runtime

Comment: Given `OtherObjects`, known at runtime, `type(OtherObjects)` is the metaclass of `OtherObjects`. So you would have to make `ComponentMetaClass` a subclass of `type(OtherObjects)`.

Comment: What if there are multiple objects as base? How do I find the meta then? can I give a tuple to type?

Comment: If `Component` has many bases, then `ComponentMetaClass` must be a subclass of all the corresponding metaclasses. You can dynamically define a subclass using the 3-argument form of `type`: `ComponentMetaClass = type('ComponentMetaClass', metabases, dct)`, where `metabases = tuple(set(type(b) for b in bases))`, and `bases` is the bases of `Component`.

Comment: Have you considered using class decorators instead of metaclasses? If class decorators suffice, then you wouldn't have all these complications...

Comment: I tried using them before, but failed to find any information how to use them. I can only find information about method decorators, and not class decorators.
What I'm trying to do is a component based class, which mixes in methods from the components. When it finds the same method already defined, it adds both methods to a list and creates a new method with same name which, when called, runs all the methods in this list.
I'm trying to make the \_\_metaclass\_\_ do this mixing operation, but failed due to the unknown baseclasses.

Comment: I think you can avoid all this complicated metaclass code if the component methods use `super`. I'll edit my post to show what I mean.

Comment: Well, I think I got my answer on how to know which \_\_metaclass\_\_' do the bases have, through type(Class). So, I'll accept your answer. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I didn't know super called both methods!! Well, I guess it was a nice afternoon spent learning the intricacies of decorators and metaclasses :P